# App Engine import ssl Failed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dropbox-api

I have an app engine app, and I am using the dropbox sdk and i get an error in the import ssl line.

Traceback

`File "/base/data/home/apps/s~email-dropbox/1.363170643114750340/dropbox/rest.py", line 11, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named _ssl`

I understand that ssl.py is a wrapper around the SSL C library, and appEngine only handles pure python. However is there no way around this? or can anyone link me to a dropbox sdk which works on app engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found a solution for this. I am posting this for anyone else who might run into the problem.

Google App Engine dosent support some python  modules with relies on C backends like the ssl module and a few others. So you cannot use the original dropbox SDK with it. However the original SDK can be patched to work with AppEngine and a few people have already done it. I used this patched version by cklein it worked like a charm.

https://github.com/cklein/dropbox-client-python

Answer (score 8):

Late for the answer, but here is how you can import SSL libraries

In you `app.yaml`, add this

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I ran into this problem using Tweepy on App Engine. Your solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: Well, this is a good solution, because it is easy and particularly clear. I've solved my trouble thank to you.